# Return statement not executing

Tags: python

So I wrote a code which is supposed to get the parent of a given node in a tree. Here is the pseudo code. Starting from the root,

```
def parent(self, child): 
    if right child exists:
        if the right child == child:
            return self
        else: self.right.parent(child)
    if left child exists:
        if the left child == child:
            print('f')
            return self
        else: self.left._get_parent(node)
```

I keep coming across this problem over and over and over again. 
For the `if the left child == child:` statement, the function DOES enter the `if` statement if it finds that either `the left child == child` or `the right child == child`.

However, the return statement does not execute this. I know this because when I wrote the `if the left child == child:` and wrote `print('f')` after it, it did print `f`, however, it did not return `self`. Does anyone know why and can anyone give a solution as to how to fix this problem?

Additionally, does anyone know how to return two statements at once NOT as tuples or lists?
For example, if I want to return 1 and 2,

```
def x(n):
    return 1, 2
```

This would return `(1, 2)`.. is there any way for it to not return it as a tuple? And just to return it normally. I'm asking this because when it comes to recursion, I want to call the same function on 1 AS WELL AS 2, and not on the tuple `(1, 2)`.

Comment: `1, 2` **is** a tuple. The parenthesis are syntactic sugar, really. Returning a tuple is *the* way to return multiple values. Just *index* the return value or use tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 2):

Your code *discards* the return values of recursive calls in the `else:` branches. You need more `return` statements:

```
if right child exists:
    if the right child == child:
        return self
    else: 
        return self.right.parent(child)
if left child exists:
    if the left child == child:
        print('f')
        return self
    else:
        return self.left._get_parent(node)
```

In Python, the expression `1, 2` creates a tuple, and that is the **canonical** way to return multiple values from functions. That is how multiple value returns work, by returning a tuple.

Simply *unpack* the returned value:

```
def foo():
   return 1, 2

value1, value2 = foo()
```

or use indexing:

```
values = foo()
values[0], values[1]
```

Comment: THE FUNCTION YOU WROTE DOES NOT WORK. IT ONLY RETURNS THE PARENT FOR THE RIGHT CHILD, BUT NOT THE LEFT CHILD.

Comment: WHY ARE WE SHOUTING? All I did was add `return` statements to your code. If your code is not returning the left child, you need to verify your algorithm.